# Validation error with skype toolbar

Tags: html

Morning!

I added the following line of code to disable the skype feature on phone numbers.

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

The problem is that it is causing the following error.

> Line 6, Column 71: Bad value SKYPE_TOOLBAR for attribute name on element meta: Keyword skype_toolbar is not registered.
>   
>   Syntax of metadata name:
>   A metadata name listed in the HTML specification or listed in the WHATWG wiki. You can register metadata names on the WHATWG wiki yourself.

Is there a work around for this? I need to ensure that the skype numbering doesn't take over the phone numbers but also validate at the same time.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit a metadata registration to the WHATWG wiki as instructed, or you can ignore the error message. Neither of these has any effect on whether your page works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML 4.01 (which lacks the HTML 5 draft's bizarre limits on what constitutes valid meta data).